# Increasing Message Size in SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, printing

I am currently writing a script that intelligently strips a database down into a series of ordered INSERT statements with seeded identity columns that will allow me to place the records into a new database without destroying any keys or relationships.

I am using the PRINT function to write the finished insert statements to the message window and saving to query to a file. However it seems like there is a max character limit for the message window, is there any way to change that?

This is a database with 120k users and I will end up with hundreds of thousands of insert statements so the file is gonna be pretty big.

Comment: Is exporting the database not good enough for you?

Comment: To elaborate, I have two massive databases, the customer wants the two databases merged into one. Because of this exporting the data to another database doesnt really help. Nor does exporting into a text file because undoubtedly there will be FK constraints violated and duplicate vals in identity columns. So the identities need to be seeded so they dont overwrite and the statements have to be executed in the correct order so as not to violate any key constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we've all had this problem at some point, I'll tell you how I ended up fixing it. Every message I wanted to output was inserted into a TEXT column on a separate table (in fact a separate database in my case). Once there you can export it to text, etc.

Comment: Ha, thats dirty but I like it! Ill try it and get back to you in a few.

Answer (score 1):

why not use:

[bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646(SQL.80).aspx)
or
[How to: Run the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

it would be incredibly slow to populate a large database with an insert for every row.

**EDIT** based on OP's comments

You could create staging tables with a single varchar(max) column that contain the actual INSERT statements.  Instead of printing the INSERT, insert it into a staging table.  You can then use BCP to export the INSERTs out from the staging tables to a file, and then just run that file (now full of INSERTs).

Comment: My response to the first comment above explains why these wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no,
From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx

> A message string can be up to 8,000
>   characters long if it is a non-Unicode
>   string, and 4,000 characters long if
>   it is a Unicode string. Longer strings
>   are truncated. The varchar(max) and
>   nvarchar(max) data types are truncated
>   to data types that are no larger than
>   varchar(8000) and nvarchar(4000).

I had to do something similar a few months back. I wrote a c# application to write the sql for me.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by printing it in a chunks

below code does it for a `NVARCHAR` variable named `@query`

```
PRINT SUBSTRING(@query, 1, 4000)
PRINT SUBSTRING(@query, 4001,8000)
PRINT SUBSTRING(@query, 8001, 12000)
PRINT SUBSTRING(@query, 12001, LEN(@query))
```